# How to activate read more from get_post_field()?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm print post content from loop by this code (Wordpress)

```
echo $content= get_post_field('post_content',$projects_posts[($i*3)+$j] ->ID );
```

Content appears with no problem but when I'm use read more option the option not work and content display full

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a stupid question but are you using this on a single post or on an archive/index page?  Asking because the "more" tag does not work on single post, only only on archive/index pages that list multiple post

Comment: I'm using "more" in index and not work may be i can't describe the problem well

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the weekend and all.  According to the docs you should be able to change 'post_content' to 'post_excerpt'  to get the results your looking for.